# Subtle differences between val and parameterless def

Tags: scala, function

Ok, this is is not another question about fundamental differences between vals & defs or functions and methods. I see that while this compiles:

```
val Extractor = new AnyRef { def unapply(s :String) => Some(s) }
val x = "hello" match { case Extractor(s) => s }
```

changing `val Extractor` to `def Extractor` breaks the code. Why is it so? It's a bit disappointing, as I hoped for complete trasnparency that would let me change the implementation from vals (generating methods anyway) to defs, or vice versa. I wonder what else can be done with one but not another?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I can supply an exhaustive list, but I can explain what's going on in this case.

`Extractor` has to be a stable identifier.  See Section 8.1.8 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).  (A `def` is not stable; a `val` is.)

Stable identifiers have certain nice properties that allow them to be more simply computed and have greater optimization possibilities.

Comment: I bet Rex could be exhaustive, or at least exhausting, but this got me a couple of times with imports.