# What's the point of declaring an object as "final"?

Tags: scala, object, inheritance, final

I just noticed that it's possible to declare objects as `final` in Scala:

```
final object O
```

What's the point of doing that? One cannot inherit from objects anyway:

```
object A
object B extends A // not found: type A
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not that anyone does this, but:

```
$ scala -Yoverride-objects
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_11).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> trait A { object O } ; trait B extends A { override object O }
defined trait A
defined trait B

scala> trait A { final object O } ; trait B extends A { override object O }
<console>:8: error: overriding object O in trait A;
 object O cannot override final member
       trait A { final object O } ; trait B extends A { override object O }
                                                                        ^
```

Possibly sometimes people want to do it. ([For instance.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/adbwUoNoHps/jQI2AggVDDkJ))

Comment: This is totally right. It took me a while to persuade myself of that, though. For a bit more verbose, painful detail, see the updates in [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265070/whats-the-point-of-nonfinal-singleton-objects-in-scala). See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308141/what-are-the-subtle-differences-between-val-and-singleton-objects)

Comment: `-Yoverride-objects` never worked well and has been removed entirely from Scala 2.13.

Comment: @SethTisue basically you are paid to spoil our fun! If only this site had tags for "opinionated Scala" vs "anything goes Scala".

Answer (score 31):

It makes no difference; object definitions are always final. The [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) explicitly mentions this in *5.4 Modifiers*:

> `final` is redundant for object definitions.

Comment: there is a recent proposal to actually forbid it: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11094

Comment: It does make a difference in the generated bytecode though. Depending on the scala version, the bytecode may or may not contain the `final` flag (2.11 adds it, 2.12 does not)