# Is there any runtime cost of "final"?

Tags: scala

I'm reading the Akka tutorial http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/guide/tutorial_3.html

There's a line of code `final case object ReadTemperature`.

Usage of the `final` modifier together with `object` already discussed in SO here: [What's the point of declaring an object as "final"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079591/whats-the-point-of-declaring-an-object-as-final) but I would like to know whether `final` also brings some runtime cost or not.

As far as I understand `final` is only relevant while compiling for overrides checks, but probably when translating to VM code there are some nuances. Would be great to hear opinions.

Comment: As far as I know, at least for what concerns Java, there is a check that a variable is final in addition to being accessible, which tells me that final modifier is retained in java byte code.  I think this check is performed regardless of whether or not a variable has final, so the performance change should be negligible.  It seems reasonable to assume the same could be said also for Scala, but then, I'm not a Scala expert.

Comment: `final`, at the class level, is usually set as a declaration which says "this class cannot, and will not be extended". It's common when you develop a framework, you have to be careful what your extensible points are.

Comment: You could benchmark it and bring in your results.  This would benefit the community.

Comment: If any, there's probably a runtime advantage. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279420/does-use-of-final-keyword-in-java-improve-the-performance

Answer (score 3):

No. Both cases are compiled down to the same output:

```
$ echo "case object ReadTemperature" > demo1.scala
$ scalac demo1.scala

$ javap -c ReadTemperature.class > demo1.out
$ javap -c ReadTemperature$.class > demo1$.out

$ echo "final case object ReadTemperature" > demo2.scala
$ scalac demo2.scala

$ javap -c ReadTemperature.class > demo2.out
$ javap -c ReadTemperature$.class > demo2$.out

$ diff demo1.out demo2.out
1c1
< Compiled from "demo1.scala"
---
> Compiled from "demo2.scala"

$ diff demo1$.out demo2$.out
1c1
< Compiled from "demo1.scala"
---
> Compiled from "demo2.scala"
```