# Uses of `final object`?

Tags: scala

Is there any purpose for a `final object`? None of the other uses of `final` seem to make any sense here:

- preventing a type from being extended (as in `final class`) doesn't make sense since `object`'s can't be extended anyways
- preventing a member from being overriden (as in `final val`) doesn't make sense since `object` members are already `final`

Are `Foo1` and `Foo2` different in any way? Perhaps in some nested context...?

```scala
final object Foo1 { val i = 7 }
object       Foo2 { val i = 7 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the point of declaring an object as "final"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079591/whats-the-point-of-declaring-an-object-as-final)

Comment: Technically speaking, they are equivalent. It was even proposed to avoid the first one to compile. But reality is that the `final` helps to iniling so I would `final object Foo1 { final val i: Int = 7 }`. Anyways most of the story can be found [here](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11094) _(which also ends in the other question liked by @lukeg)_.

Comment: @lukeg Yes, it does. Seems like `object` members are _not_ always `final`.